# Quadrature for integral of exponential of Chebyshev polynomial?

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, chebyshev-polynomials, quadrature

For Chebyshev polynomials:
\begin{align*}
T_0(x) &= 1 \\
T_1(x) &= x \\
T_2(x) &= 2x^{2} - 1 \\
& \,\,\,\vdots
\end{align*}
is there a good way to approximate the following integral?:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-1}^1 \exp\big\{a_0 T_0(x) + \cdots + a_k T_k(x)\big\} \; \text{d}x
\end{equation*}

The motivation is that I thought it might be convenient to approximate the logarithm of a probability density function using Chebyshev polynomials, but I couldn't find anything about how to normalize the approximation.

Comment: Have you attempted the change of variable $x=\cos \theta$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks; I gave that a shot, but I can't see how that helps me evaluate the integral—am I missing something obvious?

Comment: In fact your issue is to approximate the integral of $\exp(P(x))$ where $P$ is any polynomial by taking advantage of the ecomposition on the Chebyshev basis. I am afraid there is no simple general answer unless your polynomial has a particular feature.

Comment: @JeanMarie Indeed that is what I suspected; my hope was that $P$ being Chebyshev might be enough of a feature to yield some type of result. I suspect that is not the case…

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem might be to write the exponential in terms of its power series. Then $\exp(P(x))$ boils down to computing $P(x)^s$ for $s = 1,2,\dots$.

Computing $P(x) \cdot P(x)$ can be done on the level of the Chebyshev coefficients $\alpha_i$ using multiplication matrices. The definition of these matrices can for instance be found in Section 3.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2789.pdf. This allows you to compute the Chebyshev coefficients of $P(x)^s$ for arbitrarily large $s$. You can then compute the integral for each term of the (truncated) power series individually.

You can truncate the power series as long as the maximum norm of $P(x)^s$ grows slower than $1/s!$, which should asymptotically apply for every polynomial.

Alternatively, it might also be worth to take a look at the exp function in the Chebfun package (https://www.chebfun.org/), which computes a Chebyshev polynomial approximation of the exponential of a Chebyshev polynomial.

Comment: That's a fair idea. However, the original goal was to take a probability density function, and obtain an approximation that was guaranteed to be non-negative. If I have to then approximate the approximation, and I lose that guarantee, then it seems like I might as well just use a Chebyshev approximation in the first place.